# Connecting the case fan to power

Tags: motherboard, fan, computer-building, case, connector

Today was my first time building the PC from the scratch. There is only one thing left and it’s getting my case fans to spin. There are two case cables currently unplugged.

1st - it is two sided
[image]
[image]

2nd Cable
[image]

Unfortunately my pc case didn’t come with a manual (nor has one online) so I couldn’t look up what these cables are.

Where am I supposed to connect those and what’s their purpose (name)?

The motherboard is [X570 Aorus Ultra](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/X570-AORUS-ULTRA-rev-1x#kf)

Comment: Plug the top into a molex power cord from your PSU, it provides "power" to the fans.  It's a passthrough cable so you don't lose one power connector for your fans. The bottom one looks like it's for an LED controller.  Can you post your case information?

Comment: Ok, I looked at your MB, that should fit in your RBG fusion header at the bottom rear of the MB.  Does your case of RBG lighting?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Everything works great now. I don’t know how I didn’t manage to connect the molec cord. I tried it like 10 times. Anyways, feel free to post this as an answer if you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug the top into a molex power cord from your PSU, it provides power to the fans. It's a pass-through cable so you don't lose one power connector for your fans, allowing you to connect it to another device that needs power from the same type of connector.

The bottom is for an LED controller.  Looking at your motherboard, there are two "RGB Fusion" headers on the bottom near the back of the MB.  One has the same 3 pin layout as your connector and should fit.